# Maven: how to change permission of a specific type of file under a specific directory

Tags: maven

I need to change the file permission of all script files (*.sh) to "-rwxr--r--".

I am using exec-maven-plugin for that. When I am trying

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>script-chmod</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>chmod</executable>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>744</argument>
                            <argument>${SCRIPT_INSTALL_DIR}/*.sh</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

It is failing with the message that there is no *.sh file in that directory. However, if I use a specific file name, then it is a success. As there are many script files in that directory, I was trying to change the permission using *.sh.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see 2 solutions here :

1. Use `sh` as executable instead of `chmod` :

```
<configuration>
    <executable>sh</executable>
    <arguments>
        <argument>-c</argument>
        <argument>chmod 744 ${SCRIPT_INSTALL_DIR}/*.sh</argument>
    </arguments>
</configuration>
```

2. Or create a script (example `change_permissions.sh`) :

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

SCRIPT_INSTALL_DIR="$1"

chmod 744 ${SCRIPT_INSTALL_DIR}/*.sh
```

, and use it as executable :

```
<configuration>
    <executable>change_permissions.sh</executable>
    <arguments>
        <argument>${SCRIPT_INSTALL_DIR}</argument>
    </arguments>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thank much  norbjd